# Flex mx:CurrencyFormatter is not formatting correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

When i use the following formatter, I'm getting the wrong value.

```
<mx:CurrencyFormatter
        id="currencyFormatter"
        currencySymbol=""
        precision="2"
        rounding="up"
        decimalSeparatorFrom=","
        decimalSeparatorTo=","
        useNegativeSign="true"
        useThousandsSeparator="true"
        thousandsSeparatorFrom="."
        thousandsSeparatorTo="."
        alignSymbol="left" />
```

For example, if I pass the value 1.5, I'm getting as "15,00" as a result for the format method.
Does anyone knows what is happening here? Tks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
In my code I was trying to do this:

```
currencyFormatter.format(item.total.toString())
```

I resolved removing the toString method, like this:

```
currencyFormatter.format(item.total)
```

If I pass the value "1.5" as a String to the formatter, I get "15,00" as result.
But if I pass the value "1.5" as a Number, I get the correct formatting ("1,50").